# Is there a matrix $A \in \mathbb{Q}^{n \times n}$ such that $P(A)=\mathbf{0}$, where $P$ is a monic polynomial with rational coefficients?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, matrix-equations, irreducible-polynomials

Given a monic polynomial of degree $k \leq n$ with rational coefficents, can I always find a matrix $A \in \mathbb{Q}^{n \times n}$ that is a root of $P$?

**What I have already tried:**

- Using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, without success.
- I know that the minimal polynomial of $A$ (if $A$ exists) must divide $P$.
- I also tried to relate rational roots (if any exists) of $P$ with the existence of $A$ (by using the rational root theorem), but I don't know how to make any progress from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of a polynomial $p$ has characteristic polynomial $p$.

Comment: And  note that if you can find a $k\times k$ matrix that is a root, you can just augment it with zeros to get an $n\times n$ matrix that works.